# How to Automatically click Follow button with JavaScript script on page Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, automation

So to sum it up, I have been trying multiple different codes that I have found on StackOverflow and none of them seem to be working.

**My problem:**

I want to be able to automatically click a button on a website with Javascript code.

**Here is the code:**

**HTML:**

```
<label class="button slim hollow secondary ">Follow</label>
```

**JS (I am trying to use this but it is not working):**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button slim hollow secondary ")[0].click();
```

When I run the code onto the page using the console it is not working, any advice?

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: "undefined" is the only error

Comment: "TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined"?

Comment: The console literally only says undefined

Answer (score 0):

add [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) function to make the click after the window is loaded, that mean when the html is created

```js
window.onload = clicklabel();


function clicklabel(){
document.getElementsByClassName("button slim hollow secondary ")[0].click();
document.getElementsByClassName("button slim hollow secondary ")[0].style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<label class="button slim hollow secondary ">Follow</label>
<br>
<label class="button slim hollow secondary ">Follow1</label>
<br>
<label class="button slim hollow secondary ">Follow2</label>
<br>
<label class="button slim hollow secondary ">Follow3</label>
<br>
<label class="button slim hollow secondary ">Follow4</label>
<br>
<label class="button slim hollow secondary ">Follow5</label>
<br>
<label class="button slim hollow secondary ">Follow6</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple classes .. you can treat word class as attribute
     `

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('[class="button slim hollow secondary "]')[0];
btn.click();
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelector(".class1.class2")` method.

```
window.onload = doSomething;
function doSomething() {
    var btn = document.querySelector(".button.slim.hollow.secondary");
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
      console.log(this.innerHTML);
  });
  btn.click();
}
```

In console you will get 'Follow' as the result.

When the webpage loaded completely (including images), window.onload will call our doSomething function.